# HTML table markup not correct after loading from file

Tags: jquery, flask, html-table, datatable

I am designing an application where there is a requirement to load data into an HTML table from text files already having the markup data. This is part of a flask application. Here, the issue is that the data is showing up in the screen but the HTML markup is not correct. Even the number of rows are showing "0" after the load is over. Below are the relevant code data I am using currently. Any suggestions will be really helpful

## Flask Function

```
@app.route('/getfile/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getfile():
    partcntr=1
    file=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'static','testpart.txt')
    part_file=file+'.part'+str(partcntr)
    fw=open(part_file,'w')
    fw.close()
    fr=open(file,'r')
    for ind,data in enumerate(fr):
        with open(part_file,'a') as fw:
            fw.write(data)
        
        if (ind+1) % 500 == 0:
            partcntr+=1
            part_file=file+'.part'+str(partcntr)
            fw=open(part_file,'w')
            fw.close()
    
    fr.close()

    return render_template('testpartfile.html', file=url_for('static', filename='testpart.txt'), parts=partcntr)
```

## HTML Code

```
<html>
<body>
    <table id="mytab"></table>

<script>

        for (i=1;i<={{parts}};i++){
            console.log("{{file}}.part"+i)
            $('#mytab').load("{{file}}.part"+i)
            console.log($('#mytab tr').length)
        }

        console.log($('#mytab tr').length)
        $('#mytab').DataTable()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here , the statement console.log($('#mytab tr').length) always displays "0". Even the datatable does not work..

## Markup file data

Eg:- filename: testpart.txt.part1

```
<thead><tr><th>Cluster</th><th>vserver</th><th>share-name</th><th>path</th><th>share-properties</th><th>volume</th></tr></thead><tbody>
<tr><td>10.59.32.186</td><td>colomssql-u0037</td><td>admin$</td><td>/</td><td>browsable</td><td>colomssql_u0037_root</td></tr>
<tr><td>10.59.32.186</td><td>colomssql-u0037</td><td>c$</td><td>/</td><td>oplocks,browsable,changenotify,show-previous-versions</td><td>colomssql_u0037_root</td></tr>
<tr><td>10.59.32.186</td><td>colomssql-u0037</td><td>dba_mssql$</td><td>/infra_sqlarchalt_colo_fr_nosnap</td><td>oplocks,browsable,changenotify,show-previous-versions</td><td>infra_sqlarchalt_colo_fr_nosnap</td></tr>
<tr><td>10.59.32.186</td><td>colomssql-u0037</td><td>ipc$</td><td>/</td><td>browsable</td><td>colomssql_u0037_root</td></tr>
<tr><td>10.59.32.186</td><td>colomssql-u0043</td><td>admin$</td><td>/</td><td>browsable</td><td>colomssql_u0043_root</td></tr>
<tr><td>10.59.32.186</td><td>colomssql-u0043</td><td>c$</td><td>/</td><td>oplocks,browsable,changenotify,show-previous-versions</td><td>colomssql_u0043_root</td></tr>
..................
...................
```

```
Here is the table data on the browser...


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCwLQ.png
```

Comment: When you do `$('#mytab').load("{{file}}.part"+i)` it means that you are trying to load a this string, `{{file}.part1}` into your table. I think you need to replace " with `

Comment: Tried this does not work. It loads some data but the its ad-hoc and even the markup is not evident. Example:- no "thead" markup is reflecting here

Comment: Try look at this, you have to wait for the load to finish. https://api.jquery.com/load/ Use `.load(TheFilePath, function() { console.log($("#mytab tr").length)})`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution as below...

```
        jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: false }); //if order matters
        for (i=1;i<={{parts}};i++){
            $.get("{{file}}.part"+i, '', function (data) { $("#mytab").append(data); });
        }
        jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: true });  //if order matters
        $('#mytab').DataTable()
```